# Why does the method return a different value if its arguments are previously set variables rather than inputed directly?

Tags: java, arrays

Below is the relevant part of my program.

Relevant part of main method

```
    int[] C = createIntArray_descending();
    int found, target, from, to;
    int[] array;

    array = C;
    target = 5;
    from = array[0];
    to = array[array.length-1];
    printArray(array);
    bubble_sort(array);
    printArray(array);
    found = searchAscending(target, array, from, to);
    found = searchAscending(5, C, C[0], C[C.length-1]);
    System.out.println(found);
```

Method searchAscending(), a binary search method

```
 public static int searchAscending(int target, int[] array, int from, int to) {
    int mid = (from + to)/2;
    if (to<from)
        return -1; 
    else if (target == array[mid]) 
        return mid;
    else if (to == from) 
        return -1;
    else if (target < array[mid])
        return searchAscending(target, array, from, mid-1);
    else
        return searchAscending(target, array, mid+1, to);
}
```

When I run the program using

```
found = searchAscending(5, C, C[0], C[C.length-1]);
```

the method returns 4, meaning that 5 is in fact in the array C, found at position 4. I then wanted to generalise it for other arrays, so I created variables target, from, to and an empty int array, which I could then set as whatever array I wanted to apply the method to, using

```
found = searchAscending(target, array, from, to);
```

However when I run the program using this line rather than the previous one, the method returns -1 (meaning it didn't find the target, 5, in the array).

Why are they returning different values? They seem to be essentially the same to me.

EDIT:

I figured out that the problem comes from the variables from and to, the the line 
    `found = searchAscending(target, array, array[0], array[array.length-1])` 
works, so the values are successfully being passed, but `(target, array, from, array[array.length-1])` gives an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException....

Comment: Please provide a real [mcve]. You are only describing the code that leads to the failure!

Comment: What does the `bubble_sort` method do? That seems to involve `array` and not `C`, could be the source of the issue.

Comment: Why do you pass *values* to parameters `from` and `to`, when they obviously are *indexes*? `searchAscending(5, C, C[0], C[C.length-1])` should be `searchAscending(5, C, 0, C.length-1)`. And note that `array = C` doesn't *copy* the array, so `C[0]` before call to `bubble_sort()` is likely not the same as `C[0]` after call to `bubble_sort()`.

Comment: @Sasang Does it matter what `bubble_sort` does, given that `array` and `C` are referencing the **same** array?

Comment: @Sasang it seems like whatever it does to array would also happen to C

Comment: @pvg Could be terminology, but it doesn't *also* happen to `C`, because `array` *is* `C`. They reference the same array.

Comment: @Andrea not unless `array` is mapped to a new array within the function, theres a lot of weird looking code, like `if(to<from)` and `else if(to == from)` statements should be combined, for example. But here we are...

Comment: @Sasang `array` can't be mapped to a new array inside the function, because Java is pass-by-value, so the *reference value* of local variable `array` cannot be changed by the called function. The values stored *in* the array can be changed, but the function cannot cause `array` to reference a different array.

Comment: @Andrea. ofc it is. Didn't really think that through, should really sleep now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I get the same answer no matter which way I call it. However I did notice a problem with how you call your binary search function, searchAscending. For to and from you all calling it using the value at the index, rather than the index itself. Try this for your main:

```
int[] C = createIntArray_descending();
int found, target, from, to;
int[] array;

array = C;
target = 5;
from = 0;
to = array.length-1;
printArray(array);
bubble_sort(array);
printArray(array);

found = searchAscending(target, array, from, to);
System.out.println(found);
found = searchAscending(5, C, 0, C.length-1);
System.out.println(found);
```

Comment: Are you reporting some separate problem with this code? Because that doesn't really address the problem the poster is claiming to observe.

Comment: I guess so. However I believe this is the actual problem they are having, as these two calls should, and in my testing do, return the same thing.

Comment: Obviously, we'll have to wait until it's all gone through Google Translate :)

Comment: I'm confused.. to and from are supposed to be the values at the index, they represent the lowest number in the array and the highest, after it has been sorted.

EDIT:

It does work the way you suggested, but I'm confused as to whether it's doing what I mean it to do or something else?

Comment: Using binary search like you are using, you are searching based on the index locations. So to and from need to be indexes as well. It may have seemed like it was working occasionally if the list was such that each item was the same value as it's index.

Comment: @AlexandreB-k If `mid = (from + to)/2` and `array[mid]` makes sense, then `mid`, `from`, and `to` are *all* indexes, not values.

Comment: @Robert Thank you, I had misunderstood that part, which is where the problem seems to be coming from!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!!

Answer (score 0):

First, I'm going to assume `createIntArray_descending()` creates array `{5,4,3,2,1}`, and `bubble_sort(array)` correctly sorts that to `{1,2,3,4,5}`.

Your main problem is that `from` and `to` are *indexes*, but you pass in *values* from the array.

Also note that `array = C` is meaningless to your code, because it does *not* copy the array. `array` and `C` are referencing the *same* array.

To explain why it doesn't work, use a **debugger** and examine the values of your code:

```
int[] C = createIntArray_descending();              // C = {5,4,3,2,1}

array = C;                                          // array = {5,4,3,2,1}
target = 5;
from = array[0];                                    // from = 5
to = array[array.length-1];                         // to = 1
printArray(array);
bubble_sort(array);                                 // array = C = {1,2,3,4,5}
printArray(array);
found = searchAscending(target, array, from, to);   // (5, C, 5, 1) -> found = -1
found = searchAscending(5, C, C[0], C[C.length-1]); // (5, C, 1, 5) -> found = 4
System.out.println(found);
```

In both calls to `searchAscending()`, you were supposed to call with `from = 0` and `to = 4`. Both calls are incorrect.